# Running multiple instances and logging into one file at a time

Tags: enterprise-library, enterprise

I am using enterprise library 4.0 application logging block.

My project is a web services and running under IIS 7.0 and configured as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData.

The issue is due to more hits the web application creates multiple *.log files with names like some GUIDs.

Is there any configurations to set all instances to log into one file at a time and roll over based on rollInterval and rollSizeKB.